# What is the error in the code ? I want to call game, then call full name then for output

Tags: c#

```
// I want to change program 
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class DomainController : Controller
    { 
         public string Game()
         {
                public string FullName(string first, string last)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(first) && 
                                            string.IsNullOrEmpty(last))
                        return "Your First Name is = " + first;
                    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(first) && 
                                          !string.IsNullOrEmpty(last))
                        return "Last Name is = " + last;
                    else
                        return "Your First Name is = " + first + "And Last 
                          Name is = " + last;
               }

               return Game();   // I want to call this 
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to Game needs to be outside the Game method, else it will get called recursively and eventually overflow the stack.

```
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class DomainController : Controller
    {
        public string FullName(string first, string last)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(first) &&
                                    string.IsNullOrEmpty(last))
                return "Your First Name is = " + first;
            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(first) &&
                                  !string.IsNullOrEmpty(last))
                return "Last Name is = " + last;
            else
                return "Your First Name is = " + first + "And Last Name is = " + last;
        }

        public string Game(string first, string last)
        {
            return FullName(first, last);   // I want to call this 
        }
    }
}
```